# ASP.NET MVC 5 web app, Namespace does not exist?

Tags: .net, azure, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I've add this package to my WebApp (ASP.NET 5) using NuGet:
Microsoft.Azure.Devices\1.0.1

Everything fine, it will install, and show at the reference list (DNX 4.5.1). Intellisense is detecting the package.

When add an ‘using’ statement to my class I’m getting a problem:
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

When I try to build:
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Is this package not available for the framework I’m targeting? I must be doing something wrong here...

Comment: Can you show us the the "frameworks" section from your project.json? Suspect you have more than one framework listed; dnxcore is included by default.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Your awnser is pointing to the right direction.

I've removed the dnxcore 5.0 framework, this 'fixed' the problem.